# Error with unit testing and MEF

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mef

I am trying to use unit testing in an application that uses MEF to load plugins.

The line of code:

```
var dirCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(
    Path.Combine(
         Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
         "Plugins"));
```

Works perfectly fine in debug or release mode.

But if I am running a test or debugging a test it just closes the testing. No exception caught. Nothing.

I've check that the path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have a desktop application where the business logic library makes heavy use MEF and includes a number of unit tests. I built my catalog using [`AppDomain.BaseDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var location = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
var dirCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(Path.Combine(location, "Plugins"));
```

If it needs to run both in a desktop application and in the web application, try using [`AppDomain.RelativeSearchPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.relativesearchpath(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var location = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath ?? 
               AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
var dirCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(Path.Combine(location, "Plugins"));
```

Comment: The problem is not finding the path. The unit test has the correct path. It is the call to new DirectoryCatalog(... that crashes it. No exception. No feedback.

Comment: @JorgeOtero-Millan I see. I've seen some issues in the past with MEF when different OS'es or .NET versions are used. Are you running the unit tests on the same machine as the main application?

Comment: Everything on the same machine, it is just a windows forms application. Which loads some plugins from DLLs which also use some c++ dlls... That might be a clue...